# How to describe heavy rain falling on a lake and making ephemeral "pockmarks"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I am looking for a word which describes the pockmarks that heavy rainfall makes when it is falling on a lake.

[image]
<sub>*[Rain at Lake Constance by Rona-Keller](http://rona-keller.deviantart.com/art/rain-at-Lake-Constance-321702405) / deviantart.com*</sub>

Comment: surely just *splashes*?

Comment: I added a photo to this beautiful question if you don't mind.

Comment: Literally *rain drops*!

Comment: love ripples...

Comment: OP - I really like that you came up with the description "ephemeral pockmarks" so we could tell exactly what you are asking. The picture's nice too, but I got the memtal picture just from your well-chosen words.

Comment: That picture depicts a very light rain; in a hesvy rain there would be no smooth, glassy water between the drops.

Comment: In a light rain I might describe it as "the droplets dottng the surface"  in a heavy rain I'd say the [heavy] raindrops were "blanketing the surface" or even the surface was "roiling with raindrops"

Answer (score 2):

You can use the word ***dimple***, both as a noun and a verb.

> *n.* *transf.* Any slight surface depression or indentation resembling the preceding, as a dip in the surface of land or a ripple on the water. *[OED]*
>
> ---
>
> *v.* produce a dimple or dimples in the surface of: 
> *rain began to fall, dimpling the water* *[[OD]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dimple)*

Comment: Although for non-native speakers it's worth noting this word isn't particularly common, unless referring to [human facial features](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimple).

Answer (score 0):

I'd typically describe rain drops as causing ripples in the lake.  Not sure if you mean something else, due to the specification of *heavy* rain.